# Passing index of occurrence of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="Container">
    <div class="TheClass"></div>
    <div class="TheOtherClass"></div>
    <div class="TheClass"></div>
    <div class="TheOtherClass"></div>
    <div class="TheClass"></div>
    <div class="TheOtherClass"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have two classes alternating. I want to pass the index of the class TheClass in terms of its occurrence inside the container.

If I write:

```
$('#Container').on({
   click: function () { SomeFunction($(this).index()); }
}, '.TheClass');
```

and click on the last element `TheClass`, the parameter passed will be 5 but I want to receive 3 because the last `TheClass` element is the third occurrence. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) variant that takes an selector as parameter

```
$('#Container').on({
    click: function () {
        SomeFunction($(this).index('#Container .TheClass'));
    }
}, '.TheClass');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8RKJV/)

Answer (score 0):

Just define your index in terms of the the class you're trying to reference:

```
    $('#Container').on({
        click: function () { 
            SomeFunction($(this).index("." + $(this).attr('class')) + 1);
        }
    }, '.TheClass');
```

This way, your code is DRYer and more portable.